# Thermostat for Cadet Heaters Buzzes

Tags: heating

I just bought a house in August, moved in during the month of September and within the last month or two have noticed a buzzing.  At first, I couldn't figure out where it was coming from, and finally realized it was coming from the Honeywell dial-style wall thermostat which controls the two Cadet Heaters in the room and one in the kitchen.  When it is buzzing and we touch it, the buzzing stops.  There doesn't seem to be much of a correlation between the buzzing and when the heaters turn on or off, and the buzzing seems to last for a minute or two and then stops.  I'm not sure if there's an interval to when it buzzes or not (such as every two hours).

Any idea what would be causing this, or how to make it stop?

The white writing I believe says `CT410A1019` it could be `CT4|0A1019`

There is some other information in the black area at the end of the white text,

I believe this is what it says:

- The first line: 50/60 Hz
- The second line: V 120/240 [spaces] 277
- The third line: ??  22 [sapces] 19
- The fourth line: KW 255 [spaces] 5

**Update 1:**
I have turned off the power, and unscrewed the thermostat from the wall. Added those pictures to that post.  After taking the pictures, I screwed it back into the wall, and turned the power back on.  Waiting to hear the buzzing, to see if it happens again, or if doing what I did happened to jostle whatever back in place.  Will report back if I hear it again.

**Update 2:**
After thinking I had fixed it with the above update (on 12/12), the thermostat started buzzing again after about a week (on or just after 12/19).

[image: Honeywell Thermostat - Front]
[image: Honeywell Thermostat - Cover Off]
[image: Honeywell Thermostat - Connector]
[image: Honeywell Thermostat - Connector]

Comment: What model of Honeywell thermostat?

Comment: How would I determine the model?  It is a dial-style Honeywell thermostat, if that helps.  I will edit the post to include this.

Comment: Picture might be helpful. If you know how it opens there may be markings inside.  If it's a round thermostat there is a trim ring that pops off by lightly pulling.

Comment: Electric heat. Get us a picture of that thermostat or model number. Never heard an electric thermostat buzz before. Older models could have a mechanical timer in it which can buzz. That or it has a defective set of contacts which could be a fire hazard.

Comment: That looks like a line-voltage thermostat. Can you pull the cover off and post another picture of the guts and the inside of the cover? Be careful, some thermostats have normal household current rather than low voltage.

Comment: I have added the pictures to the post with the help of @JimmyFix-it.  I have also added some additional information I found on the thermostat unit.

Comment: That is indeed a line voltage thermostat (by *line voltage* I mean normal mains voltage, as opposed to lower voltage commonly used to operate many thermostats). Any buzzing from a line voltage device *could* indicate a loose wire connection and/or arcing, which could cause a fire. If you are familiar with and comfortable with working at mains voltage, shut off the power supply and check behind the base plate for signs of wire connection problems. if you are not comfortable with that, call a licensed electrician or HVAC specialist. Line voltage can shock/electrocute you.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it so turn off the breaker for that part of the house, take the thermostat off the wall and check the wires?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I have added more pictures to the post: a picture of the housing and a picture of the connection.

Comment: Good news seems to be that after unscrewing the unit from the wall, taking pictures of it, and putting it back in, the unit no longer is intermittently buzzing.  I assume whatever jostling I did during this process fixed whatever was causing the buzzing to occur.

Comment: On or around 12/19, the thermostat started buzzing again :(